# How to check if AVCaptureSession preset resolution is supported in Swift

Tags: swift, camera, resolution, avcapturesession, preset

For instance, I may want to set it to hd1280x720, but only if it's supported, and use a lower res that is supported otherwise.

```
session = AVCaptureSession()
if(**my device supports hd1280x720**){
  session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720
}else if(**my device supports 640x480**){
  session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
}
```

Comment: What about https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1389824-cansetsessionpreset ?

Comment: Very cool. Make an answer and I'll check it off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [`AVCaptureSession.canSetSessionPreset(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1389824-cansetsessionpreset):

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver can use the given preset.

Comment: This always returns true. Any other way?

Comment: @unobatbayar: Sorry, that is all I know.